# modeling a inheritance hierarchy... java

Tags: java, inheritance

> Lodgings  in  Oshkosh  can  be  classified  into  three  kinds  – Hotels  (modeled  by  the  number  of  rooms  and  star  rating),  Hostels  (modeled  by  the  number  of  rooms  and  whether  bike  rentals  are  available),  and  Bed-n-Breakfasts  (modeled  by  the  number  of  rooms  and  whether  late  arrivals are allowed). Rates per room per night are always fixed and cost $40, $20 and $55 for Hotels, Hostels and Bed-n-Breakfasts respectively.The skeleton code for an inheritance hierarchy that models this scenario is stubbed out below. Complete  all  missing  parts  so  that  the  code  compiles,  models  the  inheritance  hierarchy,  and  has  all  the  functionality  described  above.  You  should  decide  which  classes  the  appropriate  data members are stored in, and the types of those data members. In every class, complete theconstructor  and  provide a  method, computeRate,which  takes  as  parameter  the  number  of  nights  spent  and  returns  the  total room  rate  for  that  lodging.No  other  methods  should  be  provided.

Can someone give me some tips on weather you think I am going about this problem in the right way. the main thing that I am having issues with is the computeRate method. Im not sure how to set the prices of the Lodgings for hotels, Bed-n-Breakfasts, and hostels. I tried using super but im not completely sure if thats what I am supposed to do.

// parent class

```
public class Lodging
{
    int sum;
    int price;
    public Lodging( int price ) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public double computeRate(int numberOfNights){

    price *= numberOfNights;
    return sum;
}
```

// child class

```
public class Hostel extends Lodging
{
    private int numberOfRooms;
    private boolean bikeRentals;

    public Hostel( int rooms, boolean rentals) { 
        super(20);
        this.numberOfRooms = rooms;
        this.bikeRentals = rentals;   
    }  
}
```

// child class

```
public class Hotel extends Lodging
{
    private int rooms;
    private int starRating;

    public Hotel( int rooms, int starRating ) {
        super(40);
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.starRating = starRating;
    } 
}
```

// child class

```
public class BednBreakfast extends Lodging
{
    private int numberOfRooms;
    private boolean lateArrivals;

    public BednBreakfast( int rooms, boolean late ){
        super(55);
        this.numberOfRooms = rooms;
        this.late = late;
```

here is the given skeleton code

```
  class Lodging
  { 
         public Lodging(                   ) 
         { 

         } 
  }//End class Lodging 

  class Hotel 
  { 
         public Hotel(                    ) 
         {

         } 
  }//End class Hotel 

  class Hostel 
  {
         public Hostel(         ) 
         { 

         } 
  }//End class Hostel 

  class BednBreakfast 
  { 
         public BednBreakfast (       ) 
         { 

         } 
  }//End class BednBreakfast
```

Comment: what is the difference between rooms and numberOfRooms?

Comment: you're not supposed to use 'super', you should provide getters and setters (basic mutators)

Comment: there is no difference between numberOfRooms and rooms. they are the same thing but i guess i forgot to type numberOfRooms for one of them'

Comment: if they are the same, it should be in lodging, not in the other classes. They inherit whatever is in Lodging, since they extend that class

Comment: and it says that im not supposed to add any more methods so i dont think i can use mutators

Comment: Kyle, it says you're not supposed to add more methods than the ones the previous lines state you have to provide. either way, if you are not going to have mutators, it would make for a pretty useless design

Comment: also i made the bednBreakfast, hotel, and hostels class extend to Lodging so i did not have to put the computeRate method in every class. was it correct for me to do that?

Comment: that can indeed be put there, since it's shared, but you 'll need to either assign the result of your multiplication to sum, or either directly return the result of the multiplication

Comment: @Stultuske I disagree on super, he should use super and make the attribute final. Maybe add a getter but I don't see why that would be necessary, the public API seems to be computeRate, not price. Rooms should go to the superclass imho, all lodgings share this attribute.

Comment: @kutschkem yes, but not as a replacement for a setter. Hotels and BnB's are known to update their prizes, that doesn't mean they will create an entire new Hotel or BnB

Comment: @Stultuske In this toy scenario they don't, and all have the same price.

Comment: @kutschkem if the goal is to practice modeling an inheritance hiërarchy, why would they want to model a useless one?

Comment: @Stultuske to teach super?

Comment: i updated the question and added in the original given skeleton code

Answer (score 1):

Each of your classes has rooms, so I would move that to the parent class, and add it to the constructor.

Also, a `Lodging` is an abstract concept, so you cannot make a `new Lodging()`, you need a specific instance of one.

```
public abstract class Lodging {
    private double nightlyRate;
    private int capacity;

    public Lodging( int capacity, double rate ) {
        nightlyRate = rate;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public double computeRate(int numberOfNights){
        return this.nightlyRate * numberOfNights;
    }
}
```

Then, there's nothing wrong with `super(rooms, 20)`, for the `Hostel` example. It's correctly setting up the parent class's fields, and each subclass will inherit the super class's `computeRate()` method. The problem description doesn't indicate it needs to be overriden.